# Can I transfer Java code from Eclipse to Andriodstudio?

Tags: java, android

I have developed a game with Java in Eclipse, I would now like to take this 1 to 1 and make it into an app, how can I do this? Is that possible? Can I transfer this to Andriod Studio?

I don´t know how i could make this. Do you know a video or an intruduction?

Comment: Start a new Android Studio project with one empty activity  Then copy your .java files to the folder where the .java file of the new activity resides. Copy xml files to their respective res subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***android JAVA*** is kinda tricky. It violates the Java principle of **Write Once Run Anywhere**

To transfer any java project to android, it is best to:

1. Separate your Java code that handle UI from the one that handles the logique (its even better to wisely organize the project into packages
2. create a new blank android project
3. copy the *logique* Java code/classes to java resource folder
4. Convert the *UI* Java code/classes into android activities

Comment: Thank you I have also used java swing and 2dgraphics code . is this a problem if i want to implement it?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, all should be re-done. Fortunately Android Studio provides a layout editor to help you create UI faster, also in android, UI layouts are described in XML files, so its like html, not that hard

Comment: Thank you, the so i have to delete the hole code which is in combination with swing? And change it with xml?

Comment: I would recommend keeping it as a reference (outside the android project) until everything is done, just in case